# Divergent Alternating Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Need help in finding an alternating series:

> S = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}b_n$

where

> $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n = 0$
>
> $b_n > 0$ but only $\forall n \ge 1$

such that S diverges

Comment: Hint: If $b_n$ is monotonic then $S$ converges, so try looking for non-monotonic $b_n$.

Answer (score 8):

Try something like $b_{2n}=\dfrac{1}{2n}$ and $b_{2n+1}=\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$

Comment: wow that's smart.

Comment: but it is not alternating in this case

Comment: @user136895: It alternates when you multiply $b_n$ by $(-1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: @Henry yes, but if I take 2n instead of n as a variable here, I should multiply by $(-1)^{2n+1}$ which makes it not alternating

Comment: Take $b_n=n^{((-1)^n-3)/2}$ if you prefer.

Comment: @Henry and assuming $b_n=n^{((−1)n−3)/2}$ how am I sure the series is divergent?

Comment: Because the terms with one sign are effectively half a harmonic series with infinite sum while the terms with the other sign are effectively half a series with an finite sum

Answer (score 0):

$$
b_n=\frac{1}{(n+1)^p+(-1)^n},\quad 0<p\le\frac12.
$$

Comment: But if $p=1/2$ then $b_{9} = -1/2 < 0$, contradicting one of the premises of the problem ($b_{n}>0$ for all $n$).

Comment: Thanks for the observation. I have edited may answer.

Answer (score 0):

$(-1)^n \frac{n!!}{(n+1)!!}$
where

n!!= n(n-2)(n-4)...2 if n is even

n!!= n(n-2)(n-4)...3 if n is odd